# Removing the dot after the abbreviation description if extra information is given

Tags: acro

I need to remove the dots after the abbreviations in the list of abbreviations. I am using the ACRO package.

[image]

My minimum working example (MWE) looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black}

\DeclareInstance{acro-page-number}{dotfill}{default}{
punct = true,
punct-symbol = \dotfill
}

\acsetup{
list-type = table,
list-style = longtable,
list-table-width=\linewidth,
pages = first,
page-name =  ,
pages-name = ,
page-ref = dotfill
}

\DeclareAcronym{TEX}{%
    short = TEX,
    long = LaTeX,
    extra = (just gettin started)
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printacronyms
\newpage
\section{l NEED SOME HELP}
A \ac{TEX} is such a nice thing nowadays. Nevertheless, I have no clue what to do to solve this problem.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @clemens What If I need to do a breakline, and put the description below LaTeX.. in this case the open bracket stays? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the dot after “LaTeX”:

Use

```
\acsetup{
  extra-style = paren ,
  ...
}
```

and remove the parentheses from the definition of the acronym:

```
\DeclareAcronym{TEX}{
    short = \TeX,
    long  = \LaTeX,
    extra = just gettin started
}
```

Then you'll get

[image]

---

Answer to comment: placing the extra information below the description is also possible:

Define a new instance for the `acro-extra` object:

```
\DeclareInstance {acro-extra} {newline} {default}
  { brackets = false , punct = true , punct-symbol = \newline }
```

or maybe better

```
\DeclareInstance {acro-extra} {newline} {default}
  { brackets = false , punct = true , punct-symbol = \par }
```

and then set `\acsetup{extra-style = newline }`. This will give:

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black}

\DeclareInstance{acro-page-number}{dotfill}{default}{
  punct = true,
  punct-symbol = \dotfill
}

\DeclareInstance {acro-extra} {newline} {default}
  { brackets = false , punct = true , punct-symbol = \newline }

\acsetup{
  extra-style = newline,
  list-type = table,
  list-style = longtable,
  list-table-width = \linewidth,
  pages = first,
  page-name =  ,
  pages-name = ,
  page-ref = dotfill
}

\DeclareAcronym{TEX}{%
  short = \TeX,
  long  = \LaTeX,
  extra = just gettin started
}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{%
  short = foo,
  long  = foo bar baz
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\printacronyms
\newpage
\section{l NEED SOME HELP}
A \ac{TEX} is such a nice thing nowadays. Nevertheless, I have no clue what to
do to solve this problem. \ac{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I meant the dot after LaTeX =) more than enough!

Comment: @Ami would you want that line break every time the `extra` property is given?

Comment: @Ami I added something

Comment: Thank you @clemens, it's working perfect. I know these are very specific questions, but is there a way to determine that some of the extra information is depicted on the right side, because there is enough space anyways and in some cases it should be below.

Comment: @Ami Yes: use `extra-style = plain` and add `\newline` within the respective `extra` property where you want the break to appear. (There currently is a flaw in the `plain` definition. The correct one is `\DeclareInstance {acro-extra} {plain} {default} { brackets = false , punct = true , punct-symbol =  }`)

Comment: you are my hero! <3 @clemens